Handle typeof input.value for numeric value
I use Ng 14 and Reactive Forms.I want to have a input field accepting only numbers, but I want it to be customizable accepting or not positive/negative values, or decimal values.
The main solution I see, is to use a directive like it is described here for example: Angular2 - Input Field To Accept Only Numbers
However, on this, I have two questions:

About directive itself. If I use this kind of writing, then it's accessible from all the app. Isn't it an issue? It looks strange to me.

<input formControlName="myNumber" appNumericInput [allowNegative]="true" [allowDecimal]="true">

import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumericInput]'
})
export class NumericInputDirective {
  @Input() allowNegative: boolean = false; // Allow negative values
  @Input() allowDecimal: boolean = false; // Allow decimal values

// Here the code to sanitize myNumber

}


Using a simple input field, and formControl, the value is considered as a string. Then, when I use my value to set my object, this is passed as a string. Is there a way to have the control to return a numeric value? Here, it is a simple case. I can have complex objects so I wouldn't cast value by value.

const formValues = this.componentForm.value;

this.component.myNumber = formValues.myNumber;

Edit 1: Portion of concerned code. Without the directive and the properties allowNegative and allowDecimal to simplify my question 2.
<div [formGroup]="grid">
  <input class="field-input" formControlName="bottom" (input)="onlyNumbers($event)">
</div>

import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
})
export class GridComponent {

  // Input
  @Input() grid: FormGroup;

  /**
   * onlyNumbers
   */
  onlyNumbers($event){
    const input = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const controlName = input.getAttribute('formControlName');
    let sanitizedValue = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if(sanitizedValue === ''){
      sanitizedValue = null;
    }
    if (controlName) {
      if(this.grid.get(controlName)?.value !== sanitizedValue){
        this.grid.get(controlName).setValue(sanitizedValue);
      }
    }
  }
}



if you use a number type input <input type="number"/>,  half the problem will be solved, why not do that

Regarding question 1, you can limit the directive to only allow it on input elements with the following syntax: selector: 'input[appNumericInput]'

I don't use input type number because it is not possible to sanitize the value at the same time as the user is typing. For example, if the user enter '100d', the formControl set the input value to null automatically.

@ManuelaCodingPadawan please share the full directive if possible the form also

@ManuelaCodingPadawan then that 100d is the problem to tackle not this since you want a number to be stored which input number will do easily

Yes, but how to prevent the user to enter 100d without the value getting null due to formcontrol behaviour?

@ManuelaCodingPadawan updated my answer with a custom form control, which encapsulates all the logic and you just need to attach a formControlName to it.

HTML:
<input 
(input)="onChangeInput($event)" 
[value]="value" 
[min]="getMin()" 
type="number" 
(keypress)="allowDecimalCheck($event)">

You can create a custom form control which will take care of this logic, instead of the regex condition, which was giving bugs, I used keypress filtering, to filter out certain characters.
allowDecimalCheck(event: any) {
  return !this.allowDecimal
    ? event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
    : true;
}

For allowing only positive values, I used min attribute, to prevent negative values.
getMin() {
  return this.allowNegative ? -Infinity : 0;
}

Full Code:
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `
    <input 
    (input)="onChangeInput($event)" 
    [value]="value" 
    [min]="getMin()" 
    type="number" 
    (keypress)="allowDecimalCheck($event)">
  `,
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() allowNegative = false;
  @Input() allowDecimal = false;

  value!: number;
  onChange!: (value: any) => void;
  onTouched!: () => void;
  isDisabled!: boolean;

  writeValue(obj: any) {
    this.value = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (provinceData: any) => void) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  onChangeInput(e: any) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.value = value;
    this.onChange(value);
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  getMin() {
    return this.allowNegative ? -Infinity : 0;
  }

  allowDecimalCheck(event: any) {
    return !this.allowDecimal
      ? event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
      : true;
  }
}

main.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { InputComponent } from './custom-control';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, InputComponent, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <app-input formControlName="myNumber" [allowNegative]="true" [allowDecimal]="true" />
      <app-input [allowDecimal]="false"/>
    </form>

    {{form.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  form = new FormGroup({
    myNumber: new FormControl(1),
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks all for your comments. I'm gonna use part of your answers.
I get further in the code, and the component I'm using is a component from echarts and echarts is using both string and number for numbers.
Thus, I need to get them both string in the form, check the value, and if necessary cast it to number when I apply the form to the component. Finally, I'll have to do it.
Still, I'm using directive like this, and I'll improve it for decimal and negative values:
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputNumber]'
})
export class NumberDirective {

  /**
   * Constructeur
   */
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) {}

  /**
   * Ecoute de l'évènement de modification d'input
   */
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    let sanitizedValue = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (sanitizedValue === '') {
      sanitizedValue = null;
    }

    if (this.control && this.control.control?.value !== sanitizedValue) {
      this.control.control?.setValue(sanitizedValue);
    }
  }
}


just use a + to convert to number
onlyNumbers($event:any){
    const input = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const controlName = input.getAttribute('formControlName');
    let sanitizedValue:string|null = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if(sanitizedValue === ''){
      sanitizedValue = null;
    }
    if (controlName) {
        //see that you always set to +sanitize (or null)
        this.formGroup.get(controlName)?.setValue(
                   sanitizedValue?+sanitizedValue:null);
    }
  }

NOTE2: better inject the ngControl instead of use the this.grid.get(controlName)
constructor(@Optional() private control:NgControl) {}

And use
control.control.setValue("what-ever")

NOTE:If you want to take account the position of the cursor, take a look this a bit old SO
